# How can I display ads in amp pages

Tags: wordpress, adsense, amp-html

I added this code to functions.php to perform the operation,  but yet ads are not displaying on my amp pages.

```
//Adding Header Code in AMP pages in WordPress
 add_action(‘amp_post_template_head’,’nhb_amp_my_custom_head’); 
 function nhb_amp_my_custom_head($amp_template) { ?> //adsense_header_code <?php }

//Adding Footer Code in AMP pages in WordPress
 add_action(‘amp_post_template_footer’,’nhb_amp_my_custom_footer’); 
 function nhb_amp_my_custom_footer($amp_template) { ?> //adsense_body_code <?php }
```

Comment: This question as it stands doesn't really make much sense in the context of AMP. Where is your markup?

Answer (score 0):

You can display ads on your amp pages using the [`<amp-ad>`](https://www.ampproject.org/docs/reference/components/amp-ad) or [`<amp-embed>`](https://www.ampproject.org/docs/reference/components/amp-ad) tags.

> A container to display an ad. The `amp-embed` is an alias to the `amp-ad`
>   tag, deriving all of its functionality with a different tag name. Use
>   `amp-embed` when semantically more accurate. AMP documents only support
>   ads/embeds served via HTTPS.

Example: Displaying a few ads

```
<amp-ad type="a9"
    width="300"
    height="250"
    data-aax_size="300x250"
    data-aax_pubname="test123"
    data-aax_src="302">
</amp-ad>
<amp-ad width="300"
    height="250"
    type="industrybrains"
    data-width="300"
    data-height="250"
    data-cid="19626-3798936394">
</amp-ad>
<amp-embed type="taboola"
    width="400"
    height="300"
    layout="responsive"
    data-publisher="amp-demo"
    data-mode="thumbnails-a"
    data-placement="Ads Example"
    data-article="auto">
</amp-embed>
```

For more examples, you can try visiting this [link](https://ampbyexample.com/amp-ads/#amp-ads/advanced_ads).